# How do I stack 2 matrix tables into one? Row headers come from the same table

Tags: powerbi

Table 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTNZA.png)

Table 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3YTc.png)

How do I stack them together so they're in one matrix? Both row header (female, male, POC etc.) comes from the same table, and the average headcount is a measure.

I've tried summarize table and union them but it messes up the average headcount % since it's trying to sum it. I don't see a "don't summarize" option when summarizing the table.

Answer (score 0):

Open power query and append the table else if you want it to be seen as a new table just click on the arrow under append and select as a new table, the thing that you need to take into consideration while using append is both the tables should have the same header name.